# What Are Site-Wide Cookies?

Tags: website-design

Please help me by telling what is site-wide cookies in PHP. This question while reading an article. Please help. I will grateful to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Site-wide cookies are cookies that are valid in the whole site (domain).
In order to achieve this, you would need to set the correct parameters in the PHP function [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

For example:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", "example.co.uk");
```

This would be a site-wide cookie for the domain **example.co.uk**, and it would last 1 hr.

Comment: Specifically, a site-wide cookie is available on all _subdomains_ of that domain.

Comment: Let me emphasize the path attribute here ("/") that makes it site-wide. The attribute is part of all three cookie specifications (Netscape and two RFC's) and if the path attribute is missing, the current path is assumed which is the location of your cookie-setting-script (and then possibly not side-wide but bound to that location).